# New line not rendered in textarea

Tags: php

I tried to get some value populated in textarea but not getting the way I wanted it.

This is what I've done.

I'm getting some value saved in MySQL DB and keep the value in an array. For testing purpose, I'm only using a single record.

```
$sql_find_draft = "SELECT * FROM `draft` WHERE `id`=46";
$result_find_draft = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_find_draft);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result_find_draft) > 0){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_find_draft)) {
    $array_draft = array(
        "notes" => $row['notes']
    );
    }
}

$test_note_1 = $array_draft['notes'];
$test_note_2 = "This is line 1\nThis is line 2";

<textarea><?php echo $test_note_1 ?></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<textarea><?php echo $test_note_2 ?></textarea>
```

This is what I get when I do a `print_r`. Which is exactly how I stored it in MySQL

```
Array ( [notes] => This is line 1\nThis is line 2 )
```

So, why do I get different results on `$test_note_1` and `$test_note_2` on textarea like this?

https://i.ibb.co/pwGLRjN/textarea.png

I want textarea to be displaying the content like textarea2. Even both strings are the same.
Please advise.

Update :

I've fixed this with the following :

```
$test_note_1 = stripcslashes($array_draft['notes']);
```

Comment: The `\n` character shouldn't be visible if it was saved correctly  in your Mysql DB. Maybe it was escaped before being inserted? Try to see how it was saved in the DB. You can also try a `str_replace($test_note_1, '\\n', "\n")`

Comment: This is literally how its saved in the DB, without the quotes "This is line 1\nThis is line 2". And tested with str_replace, it did not work

Comment: I meant, check how you made the insert in the DB, if you escaped the character in any way. Because if you add "\n" in the DB, it shouldn't appear as "\n", it should appear as a newline. So this means that when you inserted it, you escaped it.

Comment: This is how I insert it : 
$notes = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mdl_notes']);

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this with the following :

```
$test_note_1 = stripcslashes($array_draft['notes']);
```